# How to open multiple new tabs with window.open()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, browser

In my Next.js app I would like to open a URL in a new tab programmatically after an HTTP API call is successful.

The important code in my project is the following:

```
const handleButtonClick = async () => {
  await httpResource();
  window.open(URL, '_blank');
};

return (
  <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
    Button
  </button>
);
```

When the user clicks the button once, the `URL` is opened in a new tab leaving me with the following tabs:

```
Original Tab | New Tab 1
```

However, if the user goes back to the original tab and clicks the button again, the browser goes to the previously opened tab and updates the URL in there, leaving me with the following tabs:

```
Original Tab | New Tab 2
```

Instead, I would prefer if, by clicking the button again another new tab opens, as such:

```
Original Tab | New Tab 1 | New Tab 2
```

Is this possible? I'm having trouble finding anything that would suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you spelled that correctly?  "_blank", spelled exactly that way, opens a new tab each time it is used.  If you misspelled it, then you would create a named tab that would be reused.

Comment: Are you trying to do a new tab or a new window entirely?

Comment: @TimRoberts Wow, I must be tired, I did have a typo in `_blank`. That was my issue, it is working fine now. Thank you very much!